# Reading a comma-delimited text file line-by-line in Fortran

Tags: text, file-io, fortran

I am a Fortran novice.  I would like to be able to read a text file and save its contents in individual variables.  I found a very helpful Fortran tutorial (http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~hile/fortran/fort7.htm#read), and I am trying to follow one of the examples listed there.  Specifically, I made a text file called **data.txt** with the following text:

```
1.23, 4.56, 7.89
11, 13, "Sally"
```

I have saved this text file in my current directory.  Then, I have created a file **test.f90** (also saving it in my current directory) containing the following code:

```
PROGRAM test
  IMPLICIT NONE

  REAL :: x, y, z
  INTEGER :: m, n
  CHARACTER first*20

  OPEN(UNIT = 7, FILE = "data.txt")
  READ(7,*) x, y, z
  READ(7,*) m, n, first

  PRINT *, x
  PRINT *, y
  PRINT *, z
  PRINT *, m
  PRINT *, n
  PRINT *, first
END PROGRAM test
```

I am using the GNU Fortran compiler, which I think includes the features at least up to and including Fortran95.  The above code appears to compile okay, at least with the default settings).  But when I run the resulting executable, I get this error message:

```
At line 10 of file test.f90 (unit = 7, file = 'data.txt')
Fortran runtime error: End of file
```

Line 10 is the line **READ(7,*) m, n, first**.  Can you please help me see what I am doing wrong in the above code?

Comment: Try it with another unit number ( > 10 ). Perhaps your compiler uses unit 7 for a preconnected device.

Comment: @eriktous: Thank you very much for your time, but unfortunately this does not fix the problem (at least when I use a unit of 15).  Thank you for the advice, though; it is really good to know that units of 10 or less may be used by the compiler for preconnected devices.  I will keep this in mind.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce both your exact error message and the correct output. I'm using gfortran on Windows, and Notepad to create the data file.
If you terminate the second data line with an end-of-line character (by hitting the Enter key), the program will show the correct output; if you don't terminate it, it will display the error during execution.

Basically, the runtime tries to read a line, but encounters an end-of-file character before it reaches the end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

When I your sample program, with your sample data, it worked!  Congratulations!   Output was:

```
   1.2300000    
   4.5599999    
   7.8899999    
          11
          13
 Sally
```

To guess a possible reason that it isn't working for you, sometimes Fortran executables can be sensitive to line endings, demanding the correct line-terminator for the OS, including on the last line of a data file.  Conversely many editors will silently convert line endings.  I commonly run into this problem with files written by Microsoft programs.

Comment: I indeed originally made my text file with a Microsoft editor: Notepad on Windows XP.  Just now I've made a new text file containing the same text, but this time written using XEmacs and using a unit value of 16 instead of 7 or 15.  Unfortunately, it still will not run.  Just out of curiosity, what text editor do you recommend?  Also, could it be that perhaps some Fortran dialects have a "terminator character"?  For example I know that in C, each text file must end with a "\0" or a null pointer, I think.

Comment: There is something peculiar about XEmacs, too.  When I create the text file using vi instead, it works, and I get exactly the same output as you did.  I am using the GNU Fortran compiler (gfortran); are you using it, too?

Comment: I am using gfortran with Mac OS X.   Regardless of the editor, the executable expects the OS's line terminator on the end of the line, including the last line.  As @eriktous wrote, be sure to use Enter to get a line terminator.   Microsoft programs frequently use the wrong terminator, which also causes non-obvious problems.

Comment: I am running into this same problem @M.S.B, except I am using Java to create the file read by FORTRAN and it's happening on the first read.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For some compilers it is important to add a new line after the last line with the data. For example gfortran is a compiler which needs that and it is quite logical. The Sun (Oracle) compiler doesn't need that.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as what I said?

Comment: Yes, it is. I didn't realize it after a quick read. I mainly read the slightly misguiding discussion about different editors.