# Fortran runtime error: End of file

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to understand how the READ statement works in Fortran. To do this, I've written the following simple program:

```
program main 
integer a,b,c

open(unit=10,file='test.txt',status='old')
read(10,*)a,b,c
print*,a,b,c
close(10)
end program main
```

I run this on the terminal (using a Mac): gfortran Main.f95; open a.out

I get the following error: At line 5 of file Main.f95 (unit = 10, file = 'test.txt')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

I've looked for solutions all around the web and came upon the suggestion of adding IOSTAT=... inside the READ specifiers, as follows:

```
program main 
integer a,b,c,IOstatus

open(unit=10,file='test.txt',status='old')
read(10,*,IOstat=IOstatus)a,b,c
print*,a,b,c,IOstatus
close(10)
end program main
```

When I do this, the program runs successfully. However, the print command displays "2 0 1 -1", which is erroneous as the test.txt file contains "1,2,3".

I've tried tweaking things here and there, but no good. I'm trying to do something that (I think) should be very simple: reading a list of integers from a .txt file. Any help as to what I'm doing wrong would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: What compiler version are you using? I can successfully run your initial code with gfortran 5.4

Comment: as you see, all `iostat` does for you here is suppress what was a pretty clear error message and instead give you an integer flag `-1` indicating some sort of read error.

Comment: are you certain your text file is actually a text file?  What editor do you use?

Comment: Consider this comment a side note about best practices: always use `implicit none`. When declaring variables, a double colon is optional, but common (`integer :: a,b,c`). If you declare a variable/type that has some kind of attribute, then `::` is required (`integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: a`).

Comment: I used TextEdit to create the text file. On Finder, the file kind says "Plain Text".

Also, I have added "implicit none", and I'm still getting the same error message. My version of gfortran is 6.3.

Answer (score 4):

I think that your problem is related with the `text.txt` file rather than the Fortran code. Try to add an end-of-line character (enter) in it. I have successfully run your original code with gfortran 5.4.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474410/reading-a-comma-delimited-text-file-line-by-line-in-fortran) related post for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My test.txt file is simply "1,2,3". I have now added an enter at the end of the "3". It is still giving me the same error. What text file did you use?

Perhaps it is due to my version of gfortran? I have version 6.3.

Comment: I used the same text file as you described: `1,2,3` with an enter at the end of 3. It can be possible that your text editor is doing something odd when on saving the file. Try it with another editor and see what happens.

Comment: By the way, you are not including the characters `"` on the text file right?

Comment: I am trying with Word now. When I save as plain text (txt), it gives me a few options:
1. Text encoding: Mac OS, MS-DOS, or Other encoding (and a big list of options is included).
2. Options: Insert line breaks, Allow character substitution, Add bi-directional marks, End lines with: CR only, CR/LF, LF only, or LF/CR.

Do you have any idea which options to select? 

Also, I am indeed NOT including the " characters.

Comment: You can just use nano in the terminal and it should work just fine.

Comment: I tried nano as well. Still getting the End-of-File error. Very frustrating. I've followed pretty much all the advice I've found on the web.

Comment: You can also try to use another version of gfortran but it should be working on that one anyways.

Comment: this also works for nml files, just add a enter at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is doing the right thing.  Simply testing for iostat prevents teh program from crashing.  IOstatus is set to a negative number (in this case -1) if the end of file was reached.   IOstatus is set to a positive number if there was a read error, which did not happen in your case.   Therefore, your print statement ends with -1, which is correct.