# Reading a .txt file with fortran, on a MAC

Tags: macos, fortran, gfortran

In a previous question ([Fortran runtime error: End of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46248138/fortran-runtime-error-end-of-file)), I asked why I was getting an error while reading a .txt file. I got some good feedback that I could use to get everything to work on a Windows computer. However, the problem is still persisting on my Mac computer. I am using a simple fortran code that reads a .txt file. The code works perfectly on Windows, but when I use the EXACT same fortran and .txt files on my Mac, I get end-of-file errors.
I'm wondering if someone using Mac has used gfortran to read .txt files before, and could you please tell me how you create those .txt files? What software do you use and what specifications do you use when saving the file? (I've tried a ton of different software and I keep getting the same results)

Comment: The first issue that comes to mind is [newlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline): the encoding for new lines is different on the different platforms and it may be needed to convert the files. Solutions: a "proper" text editor (TextWrangler on the mac, emacs, etc) or the conversion program "dos2unix". If this works ok, I'll re-post as an answer.

Comment: seems like a repeat of the same question. In any case assuming your file is simply 1,2,3 , run `hexdump -C` or `od -tx1` on the file (assume mac has one or the other of those) and post the result.

Comment: Hi agentp. My file is simply 1,2,3. I ran hexdump -C and got:
00000000  31 2c 32 2c 33                                    |1,2,3|
00000005;

        I also ran od -tx1 and got:
0000000    31  2c  33  2c  35                                            
0000005;

What does this mean? I created the .txt files with TextWrangler.